# Как сделать Replace для добавления текста в List<string>

Tags: c#

Уже голову себе поломал, не могу сообразить как реализовать :(

Имеется текстовый файл с кодом в ресурсах (stub)

**Stub:**

```
namespace Testovik
{
   public static class Program
   {
      Console.Read();
   }
   public static class Class1
   {
     public static List<string> ResultText()
     {
        var text = new List<string>
        {
            "[Text]",
        };
        return text;
     }
     // Должно быть так после использования Replace из формы ( редактирование кода )
  /* public static List<string> ResultText()
     {
       var text = new List<string>
       {
            "11",
            "22",
            "33",
            // и.т.д
       };
       return text;
     } */
   }
}
```

**WinForms:**

Содержимое текстового файла Stub кидаю в ресурсы

У меня на форме есть Textbox и listbox
через текстбокс вписываю текст, добавляю его в listbox.

```
 // добавляем нужный текст в listbox
 private void AddTextToListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    this.listBox1.Items.Add(this.textBox1.Text.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", ""));
    this.textBox1.Clear();
 }

// Кнопка для замены текста исходного кода в ресурсах
private void EditorStub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var editor = Properties.Resources.Stub; // Stub - это исходный код который хранится в ресурсах
   // Как мне добавить весь текст из listbox в List<string> text (исходного кода Stub )
   editor = editor.Replace("[Text]", item.ToString() + "\r\n"); // [Text] - параметр который заменяем на текст из listbox
   File.WriteAllText("NewStub.txt", editor );
}
```

Как мне добавить весь текст из `listbox` winforms в `List<string> text` (исходного кода Stub )

---

Попробовал заменить циклом чтобы весь текст из listbox записался, но записывается только одно значение!

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
  editor = editor.Replace("[Text]", "\"" + this.listBox1.Items[i] + "\",");
}
```

После получается так:

```
public static List<string> ResultText()
{
    var text = new List<string>
    {
       "11",
    };
    return text;
}
```

А как добавить и остальные ? Так же через `"[Text]",`

**[Обновление]**

Сделал так: теперь всё добавляется как нужно, но в ряд: `"11","22","33",`

```
var sbNewText = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < this.listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
  sbNewText.Append("\"" + this.listBox1.Items[i] + "\",");
}
if (sbNewText.Length > 0) sbNewText.Length--; // Убираем последную запятую
editor = editor.Replace("\"[Text]\"", sbNewText.ToString());
```

Как сделать чтобы он через новую строчку нормально записывал?

Если я пробую добавить `sbNewText.AppendLine()` то получается такая каша:
Текст уходит вообще в стенку.

```
        public static List<string> ResultText()
        {
            var text = new List<string>
            {
                "11",
"22",
"33",
"44",
,
            };
            return text;
        }
```

Comment: А логически подумать? Вы заменили `[Text]` на значение, будет потом там `[Text]`? Нет. Значит что надо сделать? Наверно, сформировать сначала текст для `Replace`, верно? Создайте переменную, куда будете `+= this.listBox1.Items[i]` делать, либо сделайте `StringBuilder`, либо используйте вовсе `string.Join()` (вместо цикла).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Если честно не понял :) Мне нужно `string.Join()` добавить куда?)

Comment: Что не понятного в том, что вам надо сначала сформировать строку со всеми значениями, а потом делать `Replace`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, А как сделать через `string.Join` за место циклов? - Обновил свой вопрос!

Comment: Вам не поможет `.Join` в решение проблемы с пробелами. Их надо вам добавить руками, либо как-то автоматизировать процесс. Ну а так, `var result = sreing.Join(',', listBox1.Items);` (первое значение, это разделитель, ставите там новую строку или что вам надо, вторым же идет коллекция).